# How to remove the Software Center in Zorin OS

Tags: apt, zorin

I am having problems with Software Center lately and i wish to reinstall it. To make sure it will not remove anything I need, I checked it with a simulated removal (`apt -s remove gnome-software`) and it showed me this:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-software-common libappstream-glib8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software-plugin-snap
  zorin-os-desktop zorin-windows-app-support-installation-shortcut
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv gnome-software-plugin-flatpak [3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1+zorin1+old1]
Remv zorin-windows-app-support-installation-shortcut [1.0]
Remv gnome-software [3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1+zorin1+old1] [gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 zorin-os-desktop:amd64 ]
Remv gnome-software-plugin-snap [3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1+zorin1+old1] [zorin-os-desktop:amd64 ]
Remv zorin-os-desktop [1.5.14]
```

I don't want it to remove `zorin-os-desktop` or any other package but solely `gnome-software`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get reinstall` allows you to reinstall a package without breaking dependency chains.

However, I find it doubtful that uninstallation/reinstallation fixes any issues with the software itself.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It fixed one of my problems which was to not install / update apps but I still have a visual problem when using dark mode where half of it is in light mode while the rest is in dark mode. Is it related to the application or a problem with gnome?

Comment: impossible to say.